# Update with Datepart a table

Tags: sql-server, datepart

Hi i have one table in sql server and i have added one bit for each week day. I have one property that's a date and i want to update all the table updating the bit depending of the dayofWeek of this date. I have read something about t-sql (datepart) but i dont know how can I do it, somebody can help me a little?

Here is a screenshot of my table

http://i.imgbox.com/adpsLL0D.jpg

For instance, in the firsts three records (2012-11-04, the last month, sunday) i want to update updating "prt_Dom" to 1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, but perhaps something like this?

```
set language spanish
go

update dbo.MyTable
set
    prt_Lun = case when datename(dw, prt_fecha) = 'Lunes' then 0x1 else 0x0 end,
    prt_Mar = case when datename(dw, prt_fecha) = 'Martes' then 0x1 else 0x0 end,
    prt_Mie = case when datename(dw, prt_fecha) = 'Miércoles' then 0x1 else 0x0 end,
    prt_Jue = case when datename(dw, prt_fecha) = 'Jueves' then 0x1 else 0x0 end,
    prt_Vie = case when datename(dw, prt_fecha) = 'Viernes' then 0x1 else 0x0 end,
    prt_Sab = case when datename(dw, prt_fecha) = 'Sábado' then 0x1 else 0x0 end,
    prt_Dom = case when datename(dw, prt_fecha) = 'Domingo' then 0x1 else 0x0 end
where
    ...
```

If your logic is really this simple then you don't need the `prt_%` columns at all, because you can always derive the bit values from `prt_fecha` on demand. But I'm guessing that you're setting defaults here that you may override later, in which case the table would make sense.

And when working with dates be careful with culture-specific settings such as `SET DATEFIRST` and `SET LANGUAGE`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
UPDATE [tableName] SET [prt_Mar] = 1 WHERE DATEPART(dw, [prt_fecha]) = 2
```

For Wednesday, you would want

```
UPDATE [tableName] SET [column] = 1 WHERE DATEPART(dw, [prt_fecha]) = 3
```

`SET DATEFIRST` is relatively important as different cultures have different 'first day of the week' numbers. There are fully deterministic ways to extract a weekday if it's something you need to do regularly.